# Speech ADC - Nyquist's Theorem for Non-Sinusoidal Waveforms

Tags: audio

This is a theory question and if better asked on a different site, would you kindly provide the site, rather than shut the question down (and I'll delete the question). I know meta.stack... is for questions about the site, but don't know where to go for general theory questions.

I know that Shannon’s theorem tell us that if we have at least 2 samples per period of a sinusoid, we have enough information to reconstruct the
sinusoid and that Nyquist's theorem tells us that we should sample at twice the highest frequency, but I'm confused about getting this frequency from a non-sinusoid. Isn't the criterion of periodicity the repetition of identical activity? Speech is rarely a sinusoid, so when converting speech from analog to digital, how is Nyquist's theorem implemented (i.e. how do we know the frequency)?

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://dsp.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus on understanding the difference between an analog curve (audio) in the time domain versus the frequency domain.  Its the same information using different representations.  When an ADC (analog to digital converter) samples this curve its digital output are points on the curve in the time domain (where time is plotted on the X axis and amplitude on Y).  As long as samples happen at least twice as frequently as the highest frequency wobble of that curve the information load is captured.  This works just fine for arbitrary curves (non-sinusoidal).

Using a Discrete Fourier Transform (fft) you can transform this information into its frequency domain counterpart while retaining all the information necessary to resurrect the source analog curve.  Here is where the representation uses sinusoidal waves.  Joseph Fourier laid down the logic which a fft uses to store as a set of sin/cos waves, along with the phase and amplitude, the frequency domain representation of the normal audio curve which is more naturally represented in the time domain.

**To summarize** :  any arbitrary analog curve (non-sinusoidal or whatever) can be stored in the frequency domain as a set (theoretically infinite set depending on desired accuracy) of structs ... each struct defines the frequency, amplitude and phase shift of a pair of cos and sin waves, each of which outputs a normal canonical sinusoidal curve.  By synthesizing and combining together the output of all these freq domain sinusoidal curves it will accurately generate the exact input analog curve which at that point will be back in the time domain

As a side note you can go from time domain to freq domain, perhaps make edits while in freq domain, then transform back to time domain endlessly

To your point of `getting the Nyquist frequency` ... you just decide the highest frequency you must capture, double it and use this frequency as your sample rate.  Of course the fidelity of the source audio curve at this Nyquist frequency is compromised since its original shape is simplified down to two points (two samples). Greater number of samples per cycle of source curve will naturally permit greater fidelity (more points along the curve are recorded). Top Tip : sample at multiples of the highest desired freq

Recently I've been coding calls to an [FFT api](https://github.com/mjibson/go-dsp) and this video hit the sweet spot on detailing some of the low level details of making sense of the frequency domain dataset returned from a FFT call when you pass in your time domain buffer [Discrete Fourier Transform - Simple Step by Step](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkGsMWi_j4Q)

Answer (score 1):

A better site for this question is http://dsp.stackexchange.com. Here is an answer to a question somewhat similar to yours (but with more complex details): https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/8078/25504

In short, Fourier Fast Transform (FFT) is used to decompose a complex signal into an equivalent sum of sinusoids.

Here is a presentation that explains this process:
http://astro.pas.rochester.edu/~aquillen/phy103/Lectures/D_Fourier.pdf

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, will do next time around. Thanks for the PDF, I'll read through it.